# CompareTo operator in breeze

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, breeze

I'm trying to do the moral equivalent of the following LINQ query using Breeze:

```
db.Customers.Where(c => c.Key.CompareTo("ALFKI") > 0)
```

(meaning - return all the customers whose Key (a string value) is "greater than" ALFKI.

I can't seem to find a CompareTo operator in breeze.js's FilterQueryOp enum.

Doing something like

```
EntityQuery.from("Customers").where("Key", ">", "ALFKI")
```

fails with EF's familiar

```
The binary operator GreaterThan is not defined for the types 'System.String' and 'System.String'.
```

Is there a way to do this kind of thing with breeze?  If not, is it a limitation of the underlying OData protocol or is this an operator that can be added to Breeze?  If there is no client-side operator that will generate the appropriate LINQ query, can I intercept on the server and inject the appropriate predicate?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was pretty trivial to implement a workaround using withParameters - like this:

```
var key = "ALFKI";
EntityQuery.from("Customers).withParameters({ Key: key })
```

...and writing the controller action like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<WebSession> WebSessions(string key)
{
    return _repository.Customers.Where(c => c.Key.CompareTo(key) > 0);
}
```

It's nice to have this level of flexibility in breeze.  It would be awesome to get the remaining LINQ operators at some point though ;-)